# How are international currencies tested for Android's in-app billing?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

Is there currently a way to fully run through international purchase flow through Google's in-app billing? I'm able to test $US purchases, but would like to test in other currencies to verify that everything is working. However, looks like I need a foreign bank account, phone number, and address if I really want to test everything end-to-end, but that is not quite feasible.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around that issue by getting google play gift cards in different currencies. Then you get yourself a VPN for your handset and go to a foreign country's store. Make one (real) purchase in that currency and your account will be locked to that one forever. Meaning afterwards you can do test purchases in that currency then. Unless you have unlimited budget, you should only pick the currencies of your major markets.

Cheers!